# How to change post status to draft in Gutenberg?

Tags: plugins, block-editor, post-status

I am writing a plugin for my own learning. With `add_meta_box` I have added some fields. There is a check for empty fields. If the required field is empty, the user sees an error message and the entry is sent to draft. If all required fields are filled in, the entry will be published.
Everything works in the classic editor. I change the post status like this:

```
    if( $this->is_required_empty() )
    {
        $data = array(
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_status'   => 'draft',
        );
        remove_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'wtmp_fields_update' ) );
        wp_update_post( $data, true );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'wtmp_fields_update' ) );
    }
```

If possible, show with an example how to send a post to draft in Gutenberg if a required field is not filled in? And how to show the error without reloading the page? For some reason I have a really hard time understanding Gutenberg.

At the moment, in Guttenberg, my entry is published even if there is an empty required field.
The error is displayed only after reloading the page like this:

```
if( wtmp_params.is_required_empty )
{
    wp.data.dispatch("core/notices").createNotice(
            "error",
            "Error text...",
            {
                    isDismissible: false,
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: this sounds like some sort of pre-publish check, libraries and examples for those already exist. Note that this will be harder to do if you're implementing your UI using the PHP metabox API

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand your comment, could you rephrase it? :)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend looking up pre-publish checks in the block editor. As I mentioned, if you built a metabox in PHP, then that makes the javascript needed to answer your question significantly harder, if it's possible at all. I don't think rephrasing will help as you would still need to research these things, and it's left a comment/hint not a full answer